# Coffeescript splats and angular's injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, browserify

In situation like this:

```
# services.coffee
module.exports = apiService : require './api-service'


# api-service.coffee
module.exports = ($http, $q, $window)->
      (config)->
         new ApiResource(config, $http, $q, $window)

class ApiResource
    constructor: (@config, @$http, @$q, @$window)->
        ....


# app.coffee
app = angular.module 'app',[]
app.factory(require('./services'))
```

How can I use injection nicely? I mean that would work if instead of using a class I'd simply do it in a function (vars would be in the same scope etc.)

I'd like to do use a class though. So what would be the best way to use coffeescript's awesome features like splats, mixins etc. with angular?

It sounds silly, however, possible, maybe?

```
 module.exports = ($http, $q, $window)->
     (config)-> new ApiResource(config) # here I need somehow to pass those args

 class ApiResource
    constructor: (args...)->
        $http = args['$http']  # or something like that...
```

Comment: What is module.exports? This is browser code.

Comment: @Fresheyeball please imagine that I'm using Browserify, thanks

Comment: Ok, where is your provider declaration?

Comment: @Fresheyeball I've updated my question, for clarity

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you want, it could look something like this, using object pattern matching:

```
class ApiResource
  constructor: ({@$http, @$q, @$window})->
    @$http ?= window.$http # set a default

config =
  $http: {foo: 'bar'}

api = new ApiResource(config)
alert api.$http.foo #=> 'bar'
```

Does that get you closer to what you want?

Comment: Honestly I don't get it. Could you elaborate? Why you passing them in curlies?

Comment: 'curlies' de-structure the incoming object and make them immediately available as `this.<thingInCurlie>` see how the `api.$http` call would work in the code example? It destructures `config` to locals. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
module.exports = (args...) ->
   new ApiResource(args...)

class ApiResource
   constructor: (args...) ->
      [@$http, @$resource] = args
```

Comment: It seems to be not working... or maybe I'm doing something wrong

Comment: yup... I mean nope, sadly angularjs injector can't figure out `args...` part.